# is there to search only for files that are at least two level deep from where i'm performing the search?

Tags: linux, filesystems

I want to check if in a certain path there is a depth of more than two levels.
for example the following are two or less level deep:

```
myfile.txt
dir1/myfile.txt
dir1/dir2/myfile.txt
```

and these will be three levels or more deep:

```
dir1/dir2/dir3/myfile.txt
dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/myfile.txt
```

is there a linux command that can do that? tell me if, or find me all files that are more than 2 levels deep?

Comment: your goal is to find myfile.txt irrespective child dir or you want to search the file exist in two child dir level?

Comment: my goal is to tell if there is a file in a depth or more than 2 level deep.
I am not interested in the file per say.
to be more exact I want to know if there is any sub directoy that is more than two level deep.
usually there is a file there, but not always.

Answer (score 1):

The `find` command has has -maxdepth and -mindepth flags.

Example:

> find $PWD  -maxdepth  2 -name myfile.txt

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
find */*/*
```

It only works if there are not too many 2-level dirs.